# Bubble sort complexity O(n)

Tags: complexity-theory, bubble-sort

We have the series of numbers.We can see that this series is ***almost*** sorted.
Since this series is ***almost sorted*** does it mean that the complexity is O(n)?

[image: Series]

Comment: That would depend on the definition of "almost sorted".

Comment: What about ( 2 3 4 5 6 1 )?  That is also almost sorted.

Answer (score 1):

No.  There are so many reasons it's hard to know where to start.  First, O() notation is not defined for specific input examples.  The complexity of an algorithm is defined for any possible input.

Aside from that, even an *almost* sorted list can require O(N^2) time to sort.  Simply take a sorted list, swap the first and last elements, and pass that to Bubble Sort.  That seems like it would meet the definition of almost sorted, but Bubble Sort will take N^2 operations to put the list in total order.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort seems to disagree.  It considers O() notation as not defined by the size of the input, but cases of input are fine - worst case, best case each can get O()'d

Comment: @DavidB wikipedia can be edited by goofballs, but O() notation for an algorithm has nothing to do with specific cases and always depends on the size of the input.  I suggest you check out Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, "Introduction to Algorithms" for an authoritative source, not wikipedia.

Comment: If wikipedia is wrong on this matter, we should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. **This example** can be considered as `O(n)`.,

There are cases when `O(n)` and even less than that is possible.

Examples-

Already sorted array `(1 2 3 4 5 6)`

An array in which only the alternate values are exchanged `(2 1 4 3 6 5)`

etc.

Keeping these best cases or exceptional cases aside, the complexity of Bubble sort for a given random unsorted array is `O(N^2)`.

Comment: this answer gives the impression you have no idea what O() notation is for.

Answer (score 0):

This is very vague, but O() notation talks about **worst-case** runtime. So whatever input is handed to bubble-sort (for instance) can take **at most** n^2 number of operations to sort. Specific examples may take anywhere from the least amount of operations possible to the most operations possible (with bubble sort that is O(n^2)).